# Read User-Defined Settings from custom .plist file

Tags: swift, xcode, plist, swift5, info-plist

I should use different API keys for different schemes (like `Debug`, `QA`, `Release`).

**And I want to use a custom `.plist` file for that (`Config.plist`). Not other ways because of my project's architecture.**

I configured `User-Defined Settings` in `Build Settings`

**I followed these steps:**

- Create a custom User-Defined Settings named `MY_API_KEY`,
- Add API key to different schemes,

[image: Custom Settings]

- Create a new `Config.plist`'s User-Defined Settings for read from `Info.plist`,

[image: Config.plist's setting]

- Write `CONFIG_FILE` to `Info.plist`,

[image: Info.plist configuration]

- Write `MY_API_KEY` to the custom plist (`Config.plist`),

[image: Config.plist setting]

So I want to read `MyAPIKey` value from `Config.plist` but it returns `${MY_API_KEY}` as a String.

Expected result is `"asdfsadf"` (value from User-Defined Settings).

---

**NOTE:**

I didn't post my way for read values from plists because I'm using my custom services for read plists.

Comment: i have exactly the same problem and question, it seems custom .plist files needs some kind of permission Info.plist already has by default. Did you find the solution? What's missing for custom .plist files to recognize ${REFERENCE_VARIABLES}?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should use **parentheses** instead of *curly braces*:

So change this:

```
${MY_API_KEY} 
${CONFIG_FILE}
```

to this:

```
$(MY_API_KEY)
$(CONFIG_FILE)
```

And second of all, why you don't use different `info.plist` files for different environments?

You can use `info.plist File` attribute to assign different `plist` files for different environments:

[image: Custom info.plist]

So you can have entirely custom `plist` file per environment.

Comment: thanks for your answer and advice but I already have different plists for different environments. But my project going to be big and I don't need to use different plists. I want to delete my all plists (I created these for different environments) and create one plist for read values from build settings (User-Defined Settings)

Comment: Did you try *parentheses*? @emrcftci

Comment: Yes I did. But it didn't work because this is not about parentheses and curly-brackets. You can check parentheses and curly brackets difference with this link ->  https://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2005/Dec/msg00480.html